# why am i getting this query failed syntax error

Tags: php, sql

I can not find out why this is not working.....
i keep getting this message

Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''laketaho_benny'.'tblPictures' SET 'caption' = 'uuuuuuuuuupppp' WHERE 'tblPic' at line 1

and this is my code

```
$sql = "UPDATE  `laketaho_benny`.`tblPictures` SET  `caption` =  `$caption` WHERE  `tblPictures`.`pictureID` =$pictureID;";
```

Comment: `'` means string literal. If you want to escape a column/table name use ` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are for strings. You're thinking of backquotes ( ` ).

Comment: like this $sql = "UPDATE  `laketaho_benny`.`tblPictures` SET  `caption` =  `$caption` WHERE  `tblPictures`.`pictureID` =$pictureID;";

Comment: Use the backquotes on column or table names. So you don't need them on `$caption` and `$pictureID`. Also, whats the type of `caption` and `pictureID`?